# RSQLite odbc dbDataType date format different

Tags: r, sqlite, odbc, rsqlite

Why is the representation of the POSIXct date format different on the same SQLite DB depending on the used driver?
The ODBC driver version 0.9996 for Windows is from:
http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(RSQLite)
library(odbc)
df <- tribble(~idx, ~date, 1, now())
df
# A tibble: 1 x 2
    idx date               
  <dbl> <dttm>             
1     1 2018-11-14 13:32:12
conFile <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "test.db")
# ODBC source test_db to be defined on the same file test.db with ODBC diver for Windows please
conOdbc <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "test_db")
dbWriteTable(conFile, "dfFile", df)
dbWriteTable(conOdbc, "dfOdbc", df)
dfFile <- tbl(conFile, "dfFile")
dfOdbc <- tbl(conOdbc, "dfOdbc")
dfFile %>% collect()
# Source:   table<dfFile> [?? x 2]
# Database: sqlite 3.22.0 [C:\Users\zfgbe\Desktop\R\test.db]
    idx        date
  <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1 1542198732.
dfOdbc %>% collect()
# Source:   table<dfOdbc> [?? x 2]
# Database: SQLite
#   3.22.0[@C:\Users\zfgbe\Desktop\R\db\test.db/C:\Users\zfgbe\Desktop\R\db\test.db]
    idx     date
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1 2018
td <- now()
dbDataType(conFile, td)
[1] "REAL"
dbDataType(conOdbc, td)
[1] "NUMERIC"
```

Comment: The two drivers serialize time values in different ways. Remember, there is no such thing as a date or time type in sqlite. The file one looks like it uses Unix time, the odbc one... Not sure unless the output of that table was truncated by the display code. https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html is essential reading about sqlite types and column affinities, though.

Comment: Thx Shawn, I also found this link about the ODBC driver http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/html/index.html 
I run into a problem by this different representation of the date format. What is the best way to represent dates in SQLite, as character?

Comment: It seams that the Windows ODBC driver converts to single quoted string  for the date format. By changing the configuration inside the Windows ODBC DNS for the test.db to use 'Julian Day conv.' this behaviour changes. But the values still differ. There for I send a mail to the developer of the driver it it's possible to add another configuration parameter to do a conversion from POSIXct representation as type real. (see value 1542198732 in the question).